# Set Mongoid localized field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

i have a localized field in both locales `en` and `it`. In my administration panel i want to set both translation though two text area in the same page

```
field :text, :type => String, localize: true
```

How can i built the forms to edit both values in Rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the Mongoid localized documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#localized_fields).

You need to set a hash `text_translations` that contains 2 keys, `en` and `it`. So you can create 2 inputs called `text_translations['en']` and `text_translations['it']` :

```
  <% ['en', 'it'].each do |key| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label key %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag "text_translations[" + key + "]", @model.text_translations[key] %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In your controller (update and create) you can do :

```
model.text_translations = params[:text_translations]
```